# Xamarin Android Emulator Issue

Tags: android, xamarin, emulation

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2022, when I start the Android Emulator running then disappearing without any errors.
I tried to start with Kernl log and I found the below.

```
[2023-03-01 16:56:16.8] 
WARNING | unexpected '-prop' value ('monodroid.avdname=pixel_5_-_api_33'), only 'qemu.*' properties are supported
[2023-03-01 16:56:16.8] 
WARNING | unexpected '-prop' value ('emu.uuid=a298103b-a231-4906-8bb9-fe8dba9b25a1'), only 'qemu.*' properties are supported
[2023-03-01 16:56:18.3] 
WARNING | *** No gRPC protection active, consider launching with the -grpc-use-jwt flag.***
[2023-03-01 16:56:18.3] 
Failed to sync vcpu reg
[2023-03-01 16:56:18.4] 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'
[2023-03-01 16:56:18.5] 
Failed to sync vcpu reg
[2023-03-01 16:56:20.0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your error message, you can fix the issue through the approaches like below:

1.Please open `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\` path, find the `intelhaxm-android.exe` and run it. Then re-create a new emulator.

2.Make sure you don't have any virtual machines running, including Docker. To check it, open task manager and kill everything that could be attached to a VM (virtual machine, docker, vagrant, etc), then restart the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved by uninstalling HAXM and reinstall again.